# Weighted reverse Poincare inequality over a function class of neural networks

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

We consider a probability measure supported on the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$, whose density is $p(x)$. We also consider a (one-layer) neural network function class $\mathcal{C}$, whose elements have the form $$
f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^rv_i\sigma(w_i^{\top}x).\tag{neural network}
$$
Here $r$ is the number of nodes in the hidden layer, $\sigma$ is the active function (such as ReLu, sigmoid), $v_i$ and $w_i$ are parameters. Such a class can also be viewed as a discretization of the integral
$$
g(x) = \int_t v(t) \sigma(w(t)^\top x) d t,\tag{continuous version}
$$
which is common in harmonic analysis. A familiar example is when $\sigma$ is a trigonometric function and $v(t)$ is a constant, it resembles the Fourier integral, where $w(t)$ is the frequency.

My question is that, under what conditions on the probability measure $p(x)$ and the structure of function class $\sigma, r,v_i,w_i $, weighted reverse Poincare inequality holds over $\mathcal{C}$? That is to say, there exists a constant $K$, such that for any $f,g \in \mathcal(C)$, the following inequality holds.
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla g(x)\|^2 p(x) dx\le K\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}| f(x)-g(x)|^2 p(x)dx.%\tag{reverse Poincare}
$$
In other words, we are able to upper bound the difference in gradients with the difference in function values (which is in the reverse direction of the commonly known Poincare inequality).